# Basic PHP question (displaying post title over thumbnail)

Tags: php, posts, post-thumbnails

I'm new to PHP so excuse the vagueness of this question. I am using a plugin called WP-Tiles that takes a group of posts and displays them in a grid. I'm calling this grid with the following function:

```
function tiles_function() { 


    $first_posts = get_posts( array( 'category' =>  47, 'posts_per_page' => 1 ));
    $second_posts = get_posts( array('category' => 7, 'posts_per_page' => 1 ));
    $third_posts =  get_posts( array('category' => 36, 'posts_per_page' => 1 ));
    $last_posts = get_posts( array( 'category' => 35, 'posts_per_page' => 1 ));
    $posts = array_merge($first_posts, $second_posts, $third_posts, $last_posts );

    // Display the tiles! (WP Tiles 1.0 only!)
    the_wp_tiles( $posts );

}
```

This is working as intended. The default behaviour of this grid is to display the post title and excerpt on hover, but I want to have the post title permanently displayed over the top of each 'tile' or post. There is no such option within the plugin settings and I'm a bit lost.

Could someone point me in the direction of what Wordpress functions I should be reading up on to achieve my goal? For instance, can include something with 'get_posts' to display the post title?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the default behaviour is to display the post title and excerpt on hover then that information should already be there. It just hidden. Most likely with CSS! So I think you should look at your CSS first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking of using the css, the problem is I can't separate the two elements (title and excerpt). Basically I want the title to be ever present, and the except appear on hover. As it stands, they both appear on hover and I can seem to isolate the title, as they are both part of one element called the 'byline'

Comment: Could you post your html? I still think its possible with just CSS unless both the title and excerpt are in a single div container or something like that.

Comment: Is it ok to link you to the site?

http://beta.phareps.org

The grid is just below the slider, under 'Latest news'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need php at all to achieve what you are after.
This can be done with just css.

This shows the title and excerpt by default.

```
.wrap .wp-tiles-byline-fade-in .wp-tiles-tile-with-image .wp-tiles-byline {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This hides the excerpt again now that we have revealed it.

```
.wrap .wp-tiles-byline-fade-in .wp-tiles-tile-with-image .wp-tiles-byline .wp-tiles-byline-content {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And this shows the excerpt again when you hover over it.

```
.wrap .wp-tiles-byline-fade-in .wp-tiles-tile-with-image:hover .wp-tiles-byline .wp-tiles-byline-content {
    opacity: 1;
}
```